# Parsing large amounts of HTML for text values using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm using Selenium and BeautifulSoup to manually crawl through web pages in a list and save the data. I'm experiencing some trouble when trying to use the `find` and `findAll` methods.

[Here's the exact HTML I'm working with](https://pastebin.com/Ja82VACS). I posted it on Pastebin because there's tons of it.

If I want to extract values within this HTML, such as the text inside of

`<div class="item value nowrap">4 Bedrooms   3 Bathrooms</div>`

Or

`<td class="value" originalvalue="6229">
6,229 sq ft
</td>`

How would I do so? I've tried using the following code:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html))
 j = soup.find('item value nowrap')[0].text
 print j`

And I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/crawl/main.py", line 39, in <module>
    j = soup.find('item value nowrap')[0].text
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? How do I get these values using BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something similar to briancaffey's answer, however, I'm using Python 2. Here's the code:

```
basic_facts_tags = soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'value'}) # Get basic facts
property_owner = basic_facts_tags[1].text # Owner of the property. 
value_per_sq_ft = basic_facts_tags[0].text # Value per sq ft according to RPR
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<html>...[paste your html here]...</html>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class":'item value nowrap'})
items = [i.text for i in items]
values = soup.find_all('td', attrs={"class":"value"})
values = [i.text.strip("\n") for i in values]
```

`find()` does not return a list, so you can't index it like you tried to do (`soup.find('item value nowrap')[0].text`)

Here's what I think you are trying to find:

```
houses = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class":"left factsSection basicFacts sectionSeparator"})

for house in houses:
    details = house.find_all('div', attrs={"class":"item"})
    print("Owner:", details[-1].find('span').text)
    print("Price/sq. foot:", details[-2].find('span').text)
```

This results in:

```
Owner: Jones Patrick Clayton
Price/sq. foot: $77
```

Comment: Really just trying to figure out a consistent way to get the data on the page that is relevant to me. I tried your solution and got the following error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: I think you are very close to getting what you need. this code worked for me (note that I just made a small edit to the last line) could you tell me which line gave you that error? @vipertherapper

Comment: this line: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
`. I'm using Python 2, do you think this is the reason for the error?

Comment: @vipertherapper possibly, I wrote this in python 3 (Anaconda distribution)

Comment: I managed to do it in Python 2, but I have this problem where some of the text within the HTML I want to extract are both `span` tags with identical tags. How can I extract them separately? If you want to look at the HTML itself, the values I want are property owner and value per sq ft.

Comment: @vipertherapper OK, I think I see what you are trying to do. I had trouble reading the HTML with no CSS. It seemed that there was only one house listed on the page. I added some code to grab the data you mentioned. Is it correct?